Bitbucket pipeline node upgrade in Makefile for Vite Build
I have these lines in my Makefile which will be executed in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml
npm install -g n;   n latest; npm update;   node -v
This will install node 22 and in node -v command, it can display node 22. However, there are additional logs are displayed.
cd apps/front;  npm install -g n;   n latest; npm update;   node -v
/usr/bin/n -> /usr/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
+ n@9.2.3
added 1 package from 2 contributors in 0.31s
  installing : node-v22.5.1
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/22.5.1
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v22.5.1/node-v22.5.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
     copying : node/22.5.1
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
   installed : v22.5.1 (with npm 10.8.2)
Note: the node command changed location and the old location may be remembered in your current shell.
         old : /usr/bin/node
         new : /usr/local/bin/node
If "node --version" shows the old version then start a new shell, or reset the location hash with:
hash -r  (for bash, zsh, ash, dash, and ksh)
rehash   (for csh and tcsh)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
(node:310) [DEP0060] DeprecationWarning: The `util._extend` API is deprecated. Please use Object.assign() instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)
v22.5.1

What do these logs mean especially the at
Note: the node command changed location and the old location may be remembered in your current shell.
         old : /usr/bin/node
         new : /usr/local/bin/node

It seems that this has affected the Vite build of my project.

Did you have node installed prior to this step? With 0 knowledge about node updates, I guess they are referring to your PATH being changed to include the new location, but it might not be updated for this instance of the shell. Also what is the actual issue this has caused?

@Randommm yes, the old version of node was from the image defined in the bitbucket.yml. It is version 12 so that is why the lines npm install -g n;   n latest; to install at least a newer version. There are no errors on the build including the vite build line but some of the pages are blank thus there are errors in Selenium tests. Locally, the selenium tests work, only in the Bitbucket pipelines.
